# Swift casting one custom type to another

Tags: swift, struct, casting

I have a function that returns "Any?" but in my particular instance, I know that it should return a custom "Tuple2" object. But since the Tuple2 is part of a separate Swift plugin, I cannot access the struct directly. I have a duplicate of that struct in my main swift code and I'm trying to cast the "Any?" result to my duplicate struct. But I cannot convince the compiler that such a cast is allowed.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

An example that outlines the problem in a single file is as follows.

```
typealias Scalar = Double

//~~~~~~ THIS HAPPENS IN THE PLUGIN ~~~~~~
struct Tuple2 {
    public var x0: Scalar
    public var x1: Scalar
    
    public init(_ x0:Scalar, _ x1:Scalar) {
        self.x0 = x0
        self.x1 = x1
    }
}

let A = Tuple2(1.0,2.0)

let B = A as! Any?

//~~~~~~ THIS HAPPENS IN MY CODE ~~~~~~
struct TupleTwo {
    public var x0: Scalar
    public var x1: Scalar
    
    public init(_ x0:Scalar, _ x1:Scalar) {
        self.x0 = x0
        self.x1 = x1
    }
}

let C = B as! TupleTwo //Error thrown here

print("x0:\(C.x0) x1:\(C.x1)")
```

Answer (score 2):

> But I cannot convince the compiler that such a cast is allowed.

Good! Because it’s not.

Swift (mostly) uses nominal typing, not structural typing. That is, two types are equal only if their (fully qualified) names are equal. Two nominal types with different names, even having the exact same content, are never equivalent.

Your copy of `TupleTwo` in this module introduces a new type that is completely unrelated to the `TupleTwo` of the other module you’re using.

To solve your problem you’ll need to import the other module, and use its `TupleTwo` type in your cast.